# DS.RESTAdapter assuming polymorphism when there is none

Tags: ember.js

I'm working with an API that I cannot alter. One of the resources it serves has a `type` property, which the RESTAdapter seems to assume is part of a polymorphic association. In this case, it isn't. So it throws errors like:

```
Error: No model was found for 'foobar'
```

Where 'foobar' is the value in the type column. Is there a way to tell Ember Data or its adapter that `type` is not part of a polymorphic association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom serializer and remove the type.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html